# esp32 EEPROM read/write cycle

Tags: esp32

I am using ESP32 module for BLE & WiFi functionality, I am writing data on EEPROM of ESP32 module after every 2 seconds.

How many read/write cycles are allowed as per standard features of ESP32 module? based on which I need to calculate EEPROM life time and number of readings (with frequency) I can store.

Answer (score 8):

The ESP32 doesn’t have an actual EEPROM; instead it uses some of its flash storage to mimic an EEPROM. The specs will depend on the specific SPI flash chip, but they’re likely to be closer to 10,000 cycles than 100,000. Writing to it every couple of seconds will likely wear it out pretty quickly - it’s not a good design choice, especially if you keep rewriting the same location.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for response. According to my requirement I need to store the data in ESP32 memory after every 2 seconds and the data should be saved after power OFF. Is there any other way around which can be used to meet the requirement? Kindly suggest.

Comment: there are few ways to go about this: save the state on a server or save the state in the RAM, however for this you will need to add a battery to your design (a lot of routers use this design to avoid writing new config to non-volatile flash).

Comment: @shruti depending on the amount of data and whether the CPU is put into deep sleep vs having power removed, you may be able to store the data in the RTC's 8K of static RAM. This survives deep sleep but not power loss. Otherwise using an SD card (which uses a different kind of more resilient flash storage) or offloading to a server on the Internet are your best bets. You can also find I2C and SPI storage devices that may work better than the ESP32's built-in flash storage.

Comment: static RAM can be used as permanent in case there's a battery with ESP32, also found  try to read flash rather than every time to write and could build an algorithm or  a logic that can manipulate in the stored data that you store may be ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm very late here, but an SD card seems like the ideal option for you. If you want to save just a few bytes, you can use FeRAM (also called FRAM). It's a combination between RAM and ROM, it's vast, and the data stays on it after power off. It is pretty expensive, so you might want to go with the SD card or web server option. I just wanted to tell you that this existed, I also know this for like a few months.

Answer (score 1):

At that write rate even automotive grade EEPROM like the 24LC001 which supports at least 1,000,000 writes will only last about 2 months!
I think microchip has EERAM which supports infinite writes and will not loose contents on power loss.
Check the microchips 47L series.